# The meaning shift when using 'the' school

Tags: grammar

So hello guys I have an issue with the grammar rule about the difference between 'the school' vs 'school'. So here is a hypothetical situation where I mention a school whose name is 'School A'. Please consider the following short paragraph:

I started going to School A since I was eleven years old. I graduated from **the** school in 2019.

I used 'the' to refer to School A I mentioned in the first sentence. But I wonder if that makes the second sentence appear to be made by someone who is not a student. Does the second sentence still sound like it was made by a student? I would be glad if any of you could help me out.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't make it sound as if it were by a non-student.
It is natural to use "the" to specify a school that has already been mentioned. It would be wrong to leave it out, because then "I graduated from school in 2019." would not necessarily mean that you graduated from school A.

You didn't ask about this, but the word "since" is not right in sentence 1. You can replace it with "when", and the sentence will be grammatically sound.